# Cannot run graphicsmagick parallel

Tags: bash, graphicsmagick, gnu-parallel

I want to run a resize job in parallel with gnu paralllel:

```
ls *.*  | parallel gm convert -gamma 0.454545 -strip -filter Lanczos -resize 1280x1280> -gamma 2.2 -format png \"{}\" \"./out/{.}-huge.png\"
```

It gives an error:

```
gm convert: Unable to open file (2.2) [No such file or directory].
```

So how do I escape ">" properly?

Comment: It is [never a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to use the output of `ls` like this. If you want to pass the list of all files in the current directory, you should use a glob expansion: `parallel ... *`. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the `parallel` command to provide any further assistance.

Comment: Parallel is for making the command run in parallel. So it autmatically splits it up on the CPU:s you have in the system. I don't know how you would do it with a for loop because then it's like it's creating many instances of gnu parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
parallel gm convert -gamma 0.454545 -strip -filter Lanczos -resize '1280x1280\>' -gamma 2.2 -format png {} ./out/{.}-huge.png ::: *
```

Or:

```
ls | parallel gm convert -gamma 0.454545 -strip -filter Lanczos -resize '1280x1280\>' -gamma 2.2 -format png {} ./out/{.}-huge.png
```

(Apart from filenames containing \n it is actually safe to pass `ls` to GNU Parallel: It will do the quoting of special chars).

Comment: It still get: "gm convert: Unable to open file (2.2) [No such file or directory]." with the "parallel gm convert -gamma 0.454545 -strip -filter Lanczos -resize 1280x1280> -gamma 2.2 -format png {} ./out/{.}-huge.png ::: *"